# Cannot get images to load in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I cannot get an image to load in Django by following the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/).

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

And here is a snippet of my code within `backend/views.py`:

```
def landing(request):
    template = loader.get_template(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'templates', 'backend', 'index.html'))
    context = {}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I have an HTML file within `templates/backend/index.html`:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'backend/example.jpg' %}" alt="My Image">
```

Any idea what might be missing?

Comment: What does your settings file look like?  Have you correctly set `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_ROOT`, and/or `STATICFILES_FINDERS`?  Are you including "django.contrib.staticfiles" in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: I have set an absolute Static URL as follows:

`STATIC_URL = '/Users/myuser/dev/backend/web/static/'` and I do have the "django.contrib.staticfiles" in `INSTALLED_APPS`. As for the `STATIC_ROOT`, that doesn't need to be there, right? Lastly, I read over the documentation for `STATICFILES_FINDERS` but couldn't figure out what it should be set to. Based on the documentation there is a default value set if you don't specify it. Should I assign this?

Comment: It looks like you've confused `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`?  `STATIC_ROOT` is meant to be the location on your local filesystem where the static assets are held.  `STATIC_URL` is the URL Path where static images are served.  For example, in one of my projects I have set `STAIC_URL` to `"/static/"` and `STATIC_ROOT` to `str(Path("/home/app/static"))`